# Using Appception for HTML5 App development, but cant figure out how the Emulator works

Tags: cross-platform

I just started using http://www.appception.com/ to see if I could develop HTML5 apps through access from web browsers.

When I run the emulator on a project with Chrome, I see a blank screen with a title noVNC; no emulator, on Safari there is additional screen "weinre" but still no emulator, I am running the emulator on Demo Projects through this platform so I assume it should work.

Would love some help especially from someone that has used Appception.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Really, the website http://www.appception.com gives us unique opportunity to develop mobile application on cloud without deploying tons of software like Android SDK, Java, Ant and Eclipse. All what you need is just a browser and mobile phone with Android or iOS.

Recently, the core engine of the Appception was rebuilt to load Android emulators and Weinre debugger faster and in guaranteed delivery time within one or two minutes. 
Please login at the site and then click Project->New, enter project name and choose desired Android SDK target and Cordova library. Click at Submit and wait until the project has been created. Next choose the project at the right project area list and click at the top menu Debug->Emulator->Build, then press Go.

As soon as you have submitted, you will be given two windows: one for emulator and another for Weinre. Please wait until emulator has been loaded ( usually it might take from 10 seconds till 2 minutes depends on the system loading). Finally you will get Android emulator with loaded package.

Through Weinre you can debug HTML and CSS layout of the package dynamically. To get access to Android log file please choose Debug->Emulator->Log

Appception has unique feature to load a package in fast mode (just few seconds) without full rebuild and re installation.